# Blank TinyMCE and 404 errors on assets

Tags: 404-error, tinymce, visual-editor

In the admin section, the visual editor (TinyMCE) has gone blank. Firebug shows a bunch of 404 errors. These files all actually exist but return a 404 when loaded as assets or when I try opening them in my browser.

I tried deactivating all plugins, as well as reinstalling WP 4.6.1 to no avail.
I have a dev copy of the site where this issue is not happening.

What could be causing a 404 on an existing file?

Answer (score 1):

Duh! It was a permissions issue: a folder inside the theme folder (containing all the files triggering the 404 errors) was set to 700 instead of 755.